# vba multiple sheets per pdf page

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, layout

The below code generates a PDF file from a dynamic array of sheets. The second code sets the print area and print titles on the individual sheets of interest. Some of the sheets have multiple, discontinuous regions set to print.

```
Worksheets(sSheetsArray).Select
sFilename = "L:\[FilePath]" & Format(Now, "DD-MMM-YY-HH-MM") & "2.pdf"
Debug.Print sFilename
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            FileName:=sFilename, _
            Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Sub to set print areas etc.

```
Sub SetWorksheetPrintArea(ws As Worksheet, sPrintAreas As String, sTitleRange As String, bLandscape As Boolean)

    With ws.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = sPrintAreas
    .PrintTitleRows = sTitleRange
    If bLandscape Then .Orientation = xlLandscape Else .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With

End Sub
```

This works, however, I need to have one sheet produce pages side by side in the PDF. This should be similar to the way it would be presented on paper if set to booklet printing. Does anyone know how this could be done without re-arranging the layout of the sheet?

Comment: I don't think there is a booklet printing feature in Excel, but you could try having a macro calculate the beginning and end of all of your pages, copy pages that will be moved as part of the booklet formatting, paste them as pictures next to another page, and set the print area to print both. Then just have another macro to go in and clean up the pasted pictures.

Comment: Can you do it without a macro first?  That is, can you click through the page layout settings and get something that matches what you want?  If so, automate those steps.  If not, then it will be quite difficult to do it with VBA.  I would start by looking at Page Layout -> Width -> 2 pages